# Rotate specific pages in djvu file?

Tags: djvu

I want to rotate a specific range of pages inside a DjVu file. How can I do it? Hopefully without quality loss. The djvu has OCR and I would like to retain that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate DJVU pages using djvused

**Download & Install**

- You can [download source forge djvu software from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/djvu/files/)
- The `INSTALL` file instruct how to perform the install
- The package includes `djvused - Multi-purpose DjVu document editor` as part of the tools directory and its man page

**Using djvused in order to rotate djvu pages**

[djvu sourceforge man page](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvused.html) suggest the following:

*Miscellaneous commands*

*set-rotation [+-]rot*

> Changes the default orientation of the selected pages. The orientation
>   is expressed as an integer in range 0..3 representing a number of 90
>   degree counter-clockwise rotations. When the argument is preceded by a
>   sign + or -, argument rot counts how many additional 90 degree
>   counter-clockwise rotations should be applied to the page. Otherwise,
>   argument rot represents the desired absolute page orientation. Only
>   DjVu pages can be rotated.

*OPTIONS*

```
-e command
```

> Cause djvused to execute the commands specified by the option argument
>   commands. It is advisable to surround the djvused commands by single
>   quotes in order to prevent unwanted shell expansion.

*Selection commands*

```
select [fileid]
```

> Select the component file identified by argument fileid. Argument
>   fileid must be either a page number or a component file identifier.
>   The select command selects all component files when the argument
>   fileid is omitted.

You can try the following command as a starting point, it should:

- select page 5
- rotate it 180 degrees
- save it in a new djvu file - p05.djvu

  djvused myfile.djvu -e 'select 5; set-rotation +2 ; save-page p05.djvu'

Comment: How do I install djvused?

Comment: @becko - I've added install details for djvused

Comment: How can I specify a range of pages? Also, I want the final djvu file to contain all the pages of the original, but a but a subset is rotted.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/djvu/files/) and install djvused (compare Yaron's answer).

#### Rotate individual page

To rotate an individual page by 180° within a DJVU file, use

```bash
djvused myfile.djvu -e 'select 5; set-rotation +2 ; save'
```

(`-e` and `set-rotation` are explained in Yaron's answer or [the djvused manpage](http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvused.html).)

#### Rotate multiple pages

To rotate a range of pages, you could run the following loop in a terminal or script:

```bash
for i in {4..8}
do
    djvused myfile.djvu -e "select $i; set-rotation +2; save"
done
```

where `{4..8}` stands for the range from 4 to 8, but you can also list numbers explicitly: `for i in 4 5 6 8`, if not all are consecutive. You can even combine both: `for i in {4..8} 15 {21..40}`.

#### Rotate a large number of pages

If you are rotating a large number of pages, you can save time by avoiding the repeated `save` command. To do this, you can use `echo` to write the `select $i; set-rotation +2` commands into a text file `command-list` (If `command-list` exists, this will delete/replace its content!):

```bash
> command-list # make command-list empty
for i in {4..8}
do
    echo "select $i; set-rotation +2" >> command-list
done
```

check the file contains the correct commands, and then apply all at once:

```bash
djvused myfile.djvu -s -f command-list
```

Here, `-s` replaces the `save` command and `-f` accepts a file containing a list of commands (instead of explicit commands after `-e`).